# Dual Core in Cooperative Game Theory

Tags: game-theory, duality-theorems

I'm a bit confused over if the dual core of a game is the same as the core of the original game. Definition of dual game:

$$ v^*(S) = v(N) - v( N \setminus S ), \forall~ S \subseteq N.\, $$

I then propose a game with two players, with v({1}) = 1, v({2}) = 1, v({1,2}) = 3. In this case it seems likt the core of the dual game is empty while the core of the original game is not. What makes me confused is the following quote from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_game:

> A cooperative game and its dual are in some sense equivalent, and they share many properties. For example, the core of a game and its dual are equal. For more details on cooperative game duality, see for instance (Bilbao 2000).

The article seems well cited and I can't seem to find any other source clearly dealing with this matter. Would be thankful for some clarification!

Comment: I suspect that in the dual, because we're now working with *cost* instead of *value*, the inequality flips in the definition of the core.

Comment: I added in my answer a link to a paper to clarify various anti-solution concepts.

Comment: I have included an addendum to clarify the relationship between the core and anti-core. I hope this helps to understand the notions.

Answer (score 1):

The core of a game is not self-dual, to see this, consider an average-convex game  quantified by (lexi-order):

```
v=[0,0,0,0,4,9,8,2,4,10,13,13,39/2,14,149/6]
```

which gives another counter-example. The core of the game is given by the following extreme points:

```
 65/6            0           13/6          71/6     
   9             0           71/6            4      
   4             0           71/6            9      
   4             0             9           71/6     
 65/6            0            10             4      
 65/6            4            10             0      
   8           16/3          23/2            0      
   8             5           71/6            0      
   9             4           71/6            0      
 19/2          16/3           10             0      
 65/6            4             0            10      
 65/6          13/6            0           71/6     
   9           16/3            0           21/2     
   9             4             0           71/6     
 19/2          16/3            0            10      
   0           16/3          23/2            8      
   0             5           71/6            8      
   0           16/3            9           21/2     
   0             4           71/6            9      
   0             4             9           71/6
```

The dual game is specified by

```
dv=[65/6,16/3,71/6,71/6,89/6,125/6,137/6,101/6,95/6,125/6,149/6,149/6,149/6,149/6,149/6]
```

one can immediately see that the core of the dual game is empty, since $65/6+16/3+71/6+71/6 = 239/6 > 149/6$. However, the core of the game coincides with the anti-core of the dual game, this can be verified while comparing set of vertices of the anti-core of the dual game with the set from above, hence

```
65/6            0           13/6          71/6     
   9             0           71/6            4      
   4             0           71/6            9      
   4             0             9           71/6     
 65/6            0            10             4      
 65/6            4            10             0      
   8           16/3          23/2            0      
   8             5           71/6            0      
   9             4           71/6            0      
 19/2          16/3           10             0      
 65/6            4             0            10      
 65/6          13/6            0           71/6     
   9           16/3            0           21/2     
   9             4             0           71/6     
 19/2          16/3            0            10      
   0           16/3          23/2            8      
   0             5           71/6            8      
   0           16/3            9           21/2     
   0             4           71/6            9      
   0             4             9           71/6
```

For completeness, the anti-core of the dual game of your example is

```
 2     1
 1     2
```

which is equal to the core.

Have a look in the original article to see if the author means actually the anti-core of the dual game. Have also a look on the following paper that should clarify various anti-solution concepts. [Article](https://dspace.wul.waseda.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2065/30543/1/SeijiKeizaigaku_363_00_009_FUNAKI.pdf)

**Addendum**

Even though, it is easily seen that the anti-core of a dual game $(N,v^{*})$ coincides with the core $C(v)$ of game $(N,v)$, there is some need to clarify the relationship. Starting with the **anti-core** $C^{\#}(v^{*})$ of a dual game $(N,v^{*})$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split} 
C^{\#}(v^{*}) & := \{\vec{x} \in \mathcal{I}(v) \,\arrowvert\; x(S) \le v^{*}(S) \;\forall\; S \subseteq N \} \\ & \Longleftrightarrow \{\vec{x} \in \mathcal{I}(v) \,\arrowvert\; x(S) + x(N\backslash S) - x(N\backslash S) \le v(N)-v(N\backslash S) \;\forall\; S \subseteq N \} \\ & \Longleftrightarrow \{\vec{x} \in \mathcal{I}(v) \,\arrowvert\; x(N\backslash S) \ge v(N\backslash S) \;\forall\; S \subseteq N \} = C(v),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
whereas $\mathcal{I}(v)$ is the pre-imputation set.